# Java Regex to match for Letter in last 3 characters of 11 character long swift code

Tags: java, regex

Working with worldwide Swift Codes.

The swift code's I'm looking to match are of the 11 character variety where the last 3 digits are alphanumeric (A-Z0-9).

The match should occur whenever a letter or letters are in the last 3 digits, in any location.

I have another regular expression that matches on Swift Codes where the last 3 digits are simply numbers only. Looks like this below.

The relevant portion would be the [0-9]{3} portion at the end, which currently hits only on numbers.

[A-Z0-9]{3} will not work correctly as it will falsely match on 3 numbers.

How would the regex be updated to match for a swift code where a letter or letters are present in the last 3 characters of an 11 character code?

```
(?:\s|\u00A0|^)((?:[A-Z]{4}[AD|AE|AF|Ag|AI|AL|AM|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BQ|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MCMD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|SS|ST|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZW]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}))(?:\s|\u00A0|$)
```

Comment: Can you post a few examples for good and bad matches?

Comment: ABCDUS12384 Match on last 3 being just numbers. 

ABCDUS12B12 ABCDUS12B1C ABCDUSAB1D9  Match on letter being in last 3 characters in any of the 3 places in any order.

Comment: Those last 3 examples should return matches "B12", "B1C", "1D9" ? Always the last 3 characters? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: It should match for the whole regex, what I mean is, the sample regular expression I left in the OP, is the one I am using to match the case where the last 3 characters are all numbers. In essence, the regex I'm looking for will while utilize the majority of the same regex but the difference will be seen in the search for the last 3 characters, where I'm not just looking for 3 digits but the possibility of having a singular or multiple letters within the 3 character ending portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more concise way, but this should do the trick for matching the 3 alphanumeric characters at the end that contain at least 1 letter.

```
[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z]
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/nV9bI7/2). See the unit tests tab on the left.

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar to this originally, but accommodating for each possible combination seemed a little tedious, which is why I asked here.